# Reading and displaying data in a specific format

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

Here is some XML:

```
<CHECKOUT>
   <EQUIPMENT path="#rtu1_130" name="RTU-1 Gym">
   <POINT ref="rstat/zone_temp">
     <notation />
     <date>Fri 17 Aug 2007</date>
     <time>10:1:22:0</time>
     <operator>th</operator>
     <done>true</done>
   </POINT>
   <POINT ref="sfan">
     <operator>th</operator>
     <done>true</done>
     <notation />
     <time>10:15:36:0</time>
     <date>Fri 17 Aug 2007</date>
   </POINT>
<EQUIPMENT path="#rtu11_130" name="RTU-11 Rm 157F">
   <POINT ref="da_temp">
     <done>true</done>
     <notation />
     <date>Mon 9 Jul 2007</date>
     <time>13:44:10:0</time>
     <operator>th</operator>
   </POINT>
   <POINT ref="clg_stg1">
     <notation />
     <done>true</done>
     <time>10:42:7:0</time>
     <date>Fri 17 Aug 2007</date>
     <operator>th</operator>
   </POINT>  
 </EQUIPMENT>
</CHECKOUT>
```

Here is my code:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("C:/Users/David/Desktop/co.xml");
XmlNodeList lstEquip = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("EQUIPMENT");
XmlNodeList lstPoint = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/CHECKOUT/EQUIPMENT/POINT");

foreach (XmlNode node1 in lstEquip)
{
  XmlElement companyElement = (XmlElement)node1;
  lstPoints.Items.Add(companyElement.Attributes["name"].InnerText);

  foreach (XmlNode node2 in lstPoint)
  {
    XmlElement companyElement2 = (XmlElement)node2;
    lstPoints.Items.Add(companyElement2.Attributes["ref"].InnerText);

  }
  lstPoints.Items.Add("*******************");
}
```

This is a "troubleshooting" app, I am not taking both elements through the lstPoints (list box) in real life but the senario applies for my problem.
The foreach will load in the lstPoints as follows:

RTU-GYM
rstat/zone_temp
Fri 17 Aug 2007
10:1:22:0
th
true.....

And it will keep going through the  all the way to the end of file. Then:

RTU-11 Rm 157F....

And will cycle through ALL the  again before it will get another .

I need the lstPoints to display like this:

RTU-Gym
rstat/zone_temp
sfan

---

RTU-11 Rm 157F
da_temp
clg_stg1

In this order....

Comment: is your XML valid because I dont see the closing tag for the First EQUIPMENT

Comment: The foreach will load in the lstPoints as follows:
     
RTU-GYM
rstat/zone_temp
Fri 17 Aug 2007
10:1:22:0
th
true.....And it will keep going through the <POINT ref> all the way to the end of file. Then:
RTU-11 Rm 157F.... And will cycle through ALL the <POINT ref> again before it will get another <EQUIPMENT name>.

I need the lstPoints to display like this:
RTU-Gym
rstat/zone_temp
sfan
***************
RTU-11 Rm 157F
da_temp
clg_stg1

In this order.... 

I am using C# windows forms. I hope you guys can give a hand out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it is valid I shortened it but all is valid with the XML. Thanks

Comment: that xml is not valid first equipment tag doesn't have an end tag. Can't be like that in your code though, xmldoc.load would fail.

Answer (score 1):

A guess given name and ref attributes are required in the xsd

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("C:/Users/David/Desktop/co.xml");
foreach(XmlNode equipmentNode in xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("EQUIPMENT"))
{
  lstPoints.Items.Add(equipmentNode.Attributes["name"].Value);
  foreach(XmlNode pointNode in equipmentNode.SelectNodes("POINT"))
  {
    lstPoints.Items.Add(pointNode.Attributes["ref"]).Value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Tony, thank you!! Sorry I copied the XML in and kind of shortened the file but its legal. Your answer is spot on.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Linq2Xml alternative

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(....);
var equipments = xDoc.Descendants("EQUIPMENT")
                .Select(eq => new
                {
                    Name = eq.Attribute("name").Value,
                    Path = eq.Attribute("path").Value,
                    Points = eq.Descendants("POINT")
                            .Select(p=>new 
                            {
                                Ref = p.Attribute("ref"),
                                Operator = p.Element("operator").Value
                            })
                            .ToArray()

                })
                .ToArray();
```

-

```
foreach (var eq in equipments)
{
    Console.WriteLine(eq.Name);
    foreach (var p in eq.Points)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + p.Ref);
    }
}
```